# Right Click menu of firefox 20 does not work in ubuntu12.04 amd64?

Tags: 12.04, firefox

After I update firefox to version 20, right-click on the web page gives almost all of menu list.
I use firefox 'Menu Editor' extension to cancel some list items in right-click menu, but I find some list items do not work such as 'Save Link As ...'.

Is here anyone who meet the same problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit for me was the Firebug add-on. Disable it, restart Firefox, and the right-click issue should be resolved. Perhaps an update to the add-on would also resolve the problem.

Hope that helps! Also hope this answer doesn't get deleted by overzealous moderators.

Answer (score 0):

I use Firebug regularly, so couldn't just disable it and upgrading to the latest version of Firebug also didn't seem to resolve it. However, reset-ing Firefox (which will remove *all* your extensions and plugins - see http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) and then re-installing Firebug 1.10.5 worked for me. I imagine, un-installing just Firebug and re-installing would also fix it.

More details on the issue can be found at http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/956675

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Disco 3! Can you please [edit] your question to include that "more info" link. That way, it's visible to everyone in the answer and not hidden away in the comments. Also, can you please include steps on how one would go about to "reset Firefox", since this is the main focus of the answer, and some people (I included) might not know how to "reset Firefox". Thanks!